# Creating a series of incremental SQL table diffs?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlite, duckdb

suppose I have a table main, and take two periodic snapshots, `t0` and `t1`.  Rows are never deleted from `main`; it has an is_deleted column for soft deletes.

```
create table t0 as select * from main;
-- wait 1 day
create table t1 as select * from main;
```

Q1.  does this command create an incremental snapshot of the main table changes?

```
create table main_diffs as
  select * from t1 except
  select * from t0;
```

Q2. Do these commands reconstitute the state of main as of t1 snapshot time (sans indexes, etc)?

```
create table main_reconstituted as select * from t0;
insert into main_reconstituted select * from main_diffs;
```

And so forth, each day capturing table $ t_{n} $ based on $ t{n-1} $?

Context: Making a daily capture of a large table's changes to distribute over a bandwidth-limited network.

Databases involved: postgresql, sqlite, duckdb.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only **one** tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I'm really using sqlite, duckdb, and postgresql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to both questions is "maybe."

For Q1, if no changes are made to the table structures, including: column order, adding or deleting columns, or column data types; then the query results in incremental row level differences.

For Q2, if the constraints listed above for Q1 are satisfied, and rows are inserted but never updated, then the end result will be that main_reconstituted has the same content as main. If updates on main are permitted and there is a suitable unique key, then an `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT UPDATE ...` can be used to achieve the desired result.

Avoid using `*` in queries, especially when column order might affect the results. If updates aren't allowed, and the primary key is a monotonically increasing value, then main_diff could also be created more efficiently by selecting all of the rows in main that have primary key values greater than the greatest in the prior day's snapshot.